# Given an integer in python return bytes 2-7 and translating java code

Tags: java, python-3.x

I am not a java dev nor a guru with dealing with bytes.

I am given this number:

trackingID = 24305955239911

I need to do the below:

```
 bytes 0-1 = internal tracking number 
 bytes 2-7 = Timestamp in nanoseconds from midnight
```

The java code for doing what is need is here:

```
public class TrackingID {

    /**
     * Returns the timestamp from TrackingId.
     * @param trackingId  - trackingId
     * @return - java.lang.Long timestamp in nanoseconds from midnight
     */
    public static long getTimestamp( long trackingId ) {
        return trackingId & 0xffffffffffffl;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the counter from TrackingId.
     * @param trackingId  - trackingId
     * @return - java.lang.Short counter
     */
    public static short getCounter( long trackingId ) {

        return (short)( trackingId >> 48 );
    }
}
```

How do I do that in python3? to get the timestamp and the counter?

Thanks

Comment: Both of the bitwise AND and right shift is available on Python too. Have you tried them?

Comment: when I do trackingId & 0xffffffffffffl I get invalid syntax. I remove the trailing l I get the same number.  what is that l? java specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume you're struggling with the Java constant `0xffffffffffffl`, you could translate that to `int('ffffffffffff', 16)`. Something like,

```
class tracking_id:
    @staticmethod
    def get_timestamp(v):
        return v & int('ffffffffffff', 16)

    @staticmethod
    def get_counter(v):
        return v >> 48


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(tracking_id.get_timestamp(24305955239911))
    print(tracking_id.get_counter(24305955239911))
```